# VSTS Nuget restore credentials

Tags: authentication, build, nuget, azure-devops

We are using a nuget package that requires authentication and are having issues when we try to build our project via VSTS builds. We can pull up the external nuget package feed from our authenticated browser and also via Visual Studio. The project builds locally and has no issues. However, when running through VSTS builds, we receive a 401 unauthorized messed even though we believe we have set things up properly.

## Setup

1. [Image of nuget task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R1rO.png)
2. [Image of authentication for nuget feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng5ov.png)
3. [Image of personal access token that is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX1Vj.png)

## Build log

Part of the log that shows that the authentication is picked up and being applied:

```
2018-03-30T19:38:43.2917713Z Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
2018-03-30T19:38:43.3113980Z Using authentication information for the following URI: https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MEE.Privacy/nuget/v3/index.json
2018-03-30T19:38:43.3123672Z [command]D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\nuget.exe sources Remove -NonInteractive -Name Privacy -ConfigFile D:\a\4\Nuget\tempNuGet_5609.config
2018-03-30T19:38:45.5301476Z Package source with Name: Privacy removed successfully.
2018-03-30T19:38:45.5348241Z [command]D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\nuget.exe sources Add -NonInteractive -Name Privacy -Source https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MEE.Privacy/nuget/v3/index.json -ConfigFile D:\a\4\Nuget\tempNuGet_5609.config -Username ******** -Password ********
2018-03-30T19:38:46.0254022Z Package Source with Name: Privacy added successfully.
2018-03-30T19:38:46.0295574Z [command]D:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\nuget.exe restore D:\a\4\s\msc\dev\Msc.Privacy\Msc.Privacy.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile D:\a\4\Nuget\tempNuGet_5609.config
```

Error that we receive when trying to find nuget package:

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in packages.config projects
Unable to find version '1.1.18087.3' of package 'Microsoft.PrivacyServices.CommandFeed.Client'.
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Microsoft.PrivacyServices.CommandFeed.Client.1.1.18087.3' is not found on source 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\'.
D:\a\4\Nuget\..\..\_Packages: Package 'Microsoft.PrivacyServices.CommandFeed.Client.1.1.18087.3' is not found on source 'D:\a\4\Nuget\..\..\_Packages'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Microsoft.PrivacyServices.CommandFeed.Client.1.1.18087.3' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MEE.Privacy/nuget/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://microsoft.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MEE.Privacy/nuget/v3/index.json.
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

## Questions

Any ideas on what we could be missing?

Comment: It works fine for me with these steps. Does that user (PAT creator) have the permission to access that feed? Try again with a new personal access token? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: Yes, that user has permission to access the feed. I recreated the token and re-ran the build and still same results. I will send you the logs with debugging info enabled.

Comment: Try to call `nuget install [package] -source Privacy` command manually, then specify customtoken as username and that pat as password, then check the result. (Remove related credential in `packageSourceCredentials` of `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config` file.

Comment: How can I run the nuget command manually, do I use 'custom' for the command type? Also, how do I remove the packageSourceCrendentials from that nuget.config file during the build process? Did you receive the logs I sent?

Comment: Just download the nuget.exe, then call `nuget.exe install [package] -source Privacy` in command prompt of local machine.

Comment: This all works on my local machine just fine. It only has issues during the VSTS build process.

Comment: Do you mean call nuget.exe install command works fine in local machine? Do you specify username and password?

Comment: On my local machine Visual Studio handles the authentication for me for this feed since I am logged into VS with an account that has access to this feed. I don't need to mess around with nuget.exe myself.

Comment: Just try it with nuget.exe to verify the access token.

Comment: It looks like the access token was the issue. I created a new access token and this time I selected 'All accessible [Microsoft] accounts' instead of the default value of my account. This seems to have been the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out our personal access token was not setup properly. When creating the token, we weren't choosing the correct account. To fix our issues, we created a new token using 'All accessible [Microsoft] accounts' instead of 'myuser1'.

[Image of personal access token creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O93Zo.png)